# pass ArrayList of ArrayList to another class

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

How to pass the `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` , for example I have created one object.

For example,

I have a class `OperationInfo` and I need to pass `ArrayList<ArrayList<OperationInfo>>` to other class. my `OperationInfo` class is parcelable.

but it seems `intent` does not allow us to pass the list of a list using `putParcelableArrayListExtra`

is there a way to pass list of list to another class ?

Comment: One way, you could serialize it to json string, pass it and deserialize back to desired list , although not efficient compared to parcel, but works.

Comment: use hashmap in putextra

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it manually looping through list and saving each sublist into bundle while having key as index along with total count

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putInt("size", mainList.size);
int key = 0;
for(ArrayList<OperationInfo> operationInfoList: mainList){
    data.putParcelableArrayListExtra(""+ (key++), operationInfoList)
}
```

Pass the above bundle and at receiving end

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<OperationInfo>> decodedList = new ArrayList<>();
 int size = getIntent().getIntExtra("size", 0);
 for(int key = 0; key < size; key++){
    decodedList.add(getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(""+(key--)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **intent.putExtra()** and pass your parceable arraylist.

And get arraylist like this in other activity

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra("param_name");
```